# Получить абзац, который содержит одно предложение оканчивающееся на знаки . ? !

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Добрый день подскажите пож-та, как получить абзац, который находится между переносами строк, содержит одно предложение оканчивающееся на знаки . ? !

Например, есть текст:

> ```
> "1)Airbus Industrie began as a consortium of European aviation firms
> ```
>
> to compete with American companies
> such as Boeing, McDonnell Douglas, and
> Lockheed. While many European aircraft
> were innovative, even the most
> successful had small production runs.
>
> ```
> 2)In 1991, Jean Pierson, then CEO and Managing Director of Airbus
> ```
>
> Industrie, described a number of
> factors which explained the dominant
> position of American aircraft
> manufacturers.
>
> ```
> 3)The land mass of the United States made air transport the favoured
> ```
>
> mode of travel; a 1942 Anglo-American
> agreement entrusted transport aircraft
> production to the US; and World War II
> had left America with a profitable,
> vigorous, powerful and structured
> aeronautical industry.
>
> ```
> 4)The retention of production and engineering assets by the partner
> ```
>
> companies in effect made Airbus
> Industrie a sales and marketing
> company. This arrangement led to
> inefficiencies due to the inherent
> conflicts of interest that the four
> partner companies faced.
>
> ```
> 5)BAE Systems and EADS transferred their production assets to the new
> ```
>
> company, Airbus SAS, in return for
> shareholdings in that company. "

Рассматриваем например второй абзац и четвертый. В четвертом два предложения, значит не подходит. Во втором одно, то что надо.

Получить абзац получилось:

```
preg_match_all("/^[\r\n](.*)[\r\n]/m", $text, $content);
```

А вот как выделить имеено одно предложение и узнать что оно одно решения не нашел, пробовал

```
(.*|\.|\?|\!)
```

но результата нет.

Comment: а третий ? ; считается концом предложения разве ? и с 5м непонятно

Comment: Так что ли ?  

    preg_match_all("/^(.*)(?<=[.?!])$/m", $text, $content);

Comment: Простите третий не доглядел там вместо ; должны быть точки

Comment: А пятый не имеет в конце перехода на новую строку

Comment: Спасибо ReinRaus! Понял смысл докручу уже как-то ;-) Еще раз спасибо;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

```
preg_match_all("/^(.*)(?<=[.?!])$/m", $text, $content);
```